# ReactJs this.props.router undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-dom

Hello I am learning React js and I have came across a problem. When I try to change back to the main page using react router i get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Here is my code, as you can see I am calling the navigate function:

[image]

My client.js with router:

[image]

If I replace `this.props.router.push('/');` with `this.props.history.push('/');` it works fine.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you add the code where you configure the router? It is most likely not passing down the props correctly (maybe your routes aren't wrapped in the <Router> tag?)

Comment: i just updated the question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are missing a constructor method with a call to `super()`. `super()` calls the constructor of the parent class and is needed to properly pass the properties of the parents class to this component. You would need this to access any properties passed to the component, including `router`.

The top of your layout class should look like this.

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  navigate() {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

[Here are the docs on how classes work in ES6!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

**Edit 1: React Router**

You also need to use the new `withRouter` when doing navigation via `this.props.router`. You do this by passing your component as an argument and exporting that. The `withRouter` function just wraps your component in another component that passes the router prop down to your component. I should point out that there are other ways of doing programmatic routing (singletons, context, etc.), but when using `this.props.router.push` you will need to use `withRouter`.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router' 
class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  navigate() {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}

export default withRouter(Layout)
```

[Using withRouter](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/cbdc49442aba5cc6f225ff5546ac5f4a217fa4ec/upgrade-guides/v2.4.0.md)

Comment: I have added constructor function but it's still saying the same error

Comment: Yes i just changed the photo

Comment: Thank you so much :), it works after i added export default withRouter(Layout)

Comment: Why does no one tell you about withRouter?!?! been googling for days :D

Comment: I can still use ```browserHistory.push``` right? Can tell difference between ```this.props.router.push``` and ```browserHistory.push``` ?