# TypeError: this.props.router is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have two React components:

**MyForm.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class MyForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, this.routerWillLeave.bind(this))
    }

    routerWillLeave(nextLocation) {
        console.log("router will leave")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="example input" />
                    <button>send!</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(MyForm)
```

**example.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  HashRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
} from "react-router-dom";
import MyForm from './MyForm.js';

class Example extends React.Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <Router>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Form</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/one">One</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/two">Two</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <Switch>
            <Route spath="/" exact component={MyForm} />
            <Route path="/one" children={<h3>One</h3>} />
            <Route path="/two" children={<h3>Two</h3>} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      );
    }
}

export default Example
```

Function `routerWillLeave` should be run when fragment identifier (what's after # in URL) is going to be changed.

But when I render `Example` component I get the following error

> TypeError: this.props.router is undefined

```
   8 | }
   9 | 
  10 | componentDidMount() {
> 11 |     this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, this.routerWillLeave.bind(this))
     | ^  12 | }
  13 | 
  14 | routerWillLeave(nextLocation) {
```

How to fix my code?

Before asking I followed the recommendations from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077351/reactjs-this-props-router-undefined) question (added `withRouter`), but the error was the same.

```
$ npm list | grep 'react-router'
├─┬ react-router-dom@5.2.0
│ ├─┬ react-router@5.2.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.17.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.17.1
$ cat package.json | grep 'react-router'
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

Comment: which version of react-router do you use. Seems like you are using an old pattern

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, I'm not sure I correctly checked the version, but I updated my question.

Comment: `routerWillLeave` is supposed to have some logic of simply shows a prompt

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, it's supposed to have some logic